# Weighted. mean error in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, weighted-average

I have created the following data frame

```
 df<-data.frame("A"<-c(1:20), "B"<-c(21:40),"C"<-c(11:30))
 names(df)<-c("A", "B", "C")
 nameslist<-c("A", "B")
```

I am trying to obtain the mean and weighted means for both columns combined

I have tried this

```
   mean(df[,names(df)[names(df)%in%nameslist]])
```

I get the following error.

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(df[, names(df)[names(df) %in% nameslist]]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have also tried computing the weighted mean as follows

```
 weighted.mean(df[,names(df)[names(df)%in%nameslist]])
 410
```

I am getting an output of 410 in this case. I am unable to uncover where I am wrong. I request someone to guide me here

Comment: Extract columns from `df` passing name vector and calculate mean on matrix with: `mean(t(df[, nameslist]))`

Comment: `df <- data.frame(A=c(1:20), B=c(21:40), C=(11:30)); 
sapply(df[, c("A", "B")], mean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obteain the global mean of columns A and B, try this code:

```
mean(unlist(df[,which(colnames(df)%in%nameslist)]))
[1] 20.5
```

About `weighted.mean` you have first to define `w`:

```
w   
a numerical vector of weights the same length as x giving the weights to use for elements of x.
```

An example:

```
w<-c(0.5,1)   
weighted.mean(unlist(df[,which(colnames(df)%in%nameslist)]),c(rep(w[1],nrow(df)),rep(w[2],nrow(df))))
        [1] 23.83333
```

Update:
if you want to derive weights based on the number of rows with values greater than zero, a solution:

```
w<-c(mean(df[,1]>0),mean(df[,2]>0))
```

---

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way we can derive weights based on the frequency of occurence of the variable or the number of rows with values greater than zero

Comment: Updated example of w based on values.